# Finding all points withing a bounding box

Tags: java, algorithm

I have been searching the internet for about a day and I can not seem to find an algorithm to find all points within a bounding box.

Picture:
[image]

The accuracy also needs to be 8 decimal digits long.

Example:
(0,0)
(0,0.00000001)
(0,0.00000002)
etc..
(80,80.45356433)

Comment: What exactly is the question? You can iterate over all points at any level of accuracy.

Comment: What are you trying to do? maybe it's another way to implement what you want?

Comment: Like Simeon Visser said. iterate over all points withing a bouding box

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you want to print the points on the screen or write to a file?

Comment: What sort of coordinate system are these corners in? I tried counting how many "points" there are in there, with a granularity of 100 million ppu, but I can't work out the width and height.

Comment: @Jongware latitude and longitude

Comment: Sure (that explains the 90 and 180), but I don't think this is a rectangle in *any* coordinate system. Should there not be an equal long *or* lat value in any two consecutive corners?

Comment: Well treating them like regular points on Cartesian coordinate plane and it forms a rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    long p = (long)Math.pow(10, 8);
    long start = 90 * p;
    long end = 180 * p;
    for (long i = start; i < end; i++) {
        for (long j = start; j < end; j++) {
            System.out.println("(" + (double)i / p + "," + (double)j / p + ")");
        }
    }
```

will take a while

Comment: instead of doubles, it is better to use longs -- it'd be faster and more precise

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you mean by *finding all points inside a box*. There is just too many!

I would suggest using an *Identifier* function, i.e., given a point (x, y), I(x, y) = 1 if and only if the point (x, y) is inside your box.

A call to the identifier in your example requires $4$ comparisons.

```
    public class Box {
          /**
           * Identifier function.
           * @param x  x-coordinate of input point
           * @param y  y-coordinate of input point
           * @return True if and only if the given point is inside the box.
           */
          public boolean IsInside(double x, double y) {
              return (this.x_min <= x) && (this.x_max >= x) &&
                     (this.y_max >= y) && (this.y_min <= y);
           }
          double x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max; // or do it with left top width and height 
     }
```

I hope it helps.